# Multiple tabbed grids but record info only referencing to the grid in the first tab

Tags: forms, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I've got a form done in x++ (formBuild) and I managed to display different grids in different tabs. However, when I do a right-click record info on any of the grids other than the first one, the details are that of the first grid. Eg. The second row of grid 2 when I do a record info is actually the second row of grid 1.

One thing is all the grids are actually using the same table, just having different query ranges for each.

Any way to fix this?

**Added code snippets**

Making the grid:

```
for (counter = 0; counter < locations.lastIndex(); counter++)
{
    formBuildDatasource = form.addDataSource(tableStr(SomeTable));
    formBuildTabPageControl = formBuildTabControl.addControl(FormControlType::TabPage, locations.value(counter+1));
    formBuildTabPageControl.caption(locations.value(counter+1));
    formBuildGridControl = formBuildTabPageControl.addControl(FormControlType::Grid, locations.value(counter+1));
    formBuildGridControl.allowEdit(0);
    formBuildGridControl.dataSource(formBuildDatasource);
    formBuildGridControl.height(500,-1);
    formBuildGridControl.width(550,-1);
    formBuildGridControl.addDataField(formBuildDatasource.id(), fieldNum(SomeTable, MachineId));
    formBuildGridControl.addDataField(formBuildDatasource.id(), fieldNum(SomeTable, MachineStatus));

}
```

Adding the query:

```
for (counter = 0; counter < locations.lastIndex(); counter++)
{
    fds = formRun.dataSource(counter+1);
    qbds = fds.query().dataSourceNo(1);
    qbr = Qbds.addRange(fieldnum(SomeTable, MachineLocation));
    qbr.value(locations.value(counter+1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer to your prior question applies here as well:

[Adding view/temporary table records to Form Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676612/ax-2012-adding-view-temporary-table-records-to-form-grid-through-x/20680718#20680718)

You will have to use more than one datasource (using the same table). Remember to change the `datasource` attribute of the grids to match the correct one. My guess would be that they currently all reference the same datasource.

Comment: There's actually one datasource for each grid using the same table too. I checked by going to personalize -> query on the form that comes out. As this form was done through X++, I duplicated the form through the dragging and dropping of AOT. That form is able to work properly, and the personalize -> query looks the same as the form done through X++. Also, the x++ form, when i check the checkbox for the record, it checks for all the grids(in the different tabs) that are in the same row too, which is wrong

Comment: PS: I'm using x++ to create the form as I have to dynamically add grids/tabs depending on the `locations` created, so if a new location comes up in the future this form will have an additional grid/tab

Comment: Try saving your run-time generated form in the AOT. Then analyze or debug the saved form.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a query + view of the table, and have that as the 'child' entity?

I don't know why you can't have the same table referenced twice in the same form data sources, however.  Ensure that the link between the tables are defined correctly, and you have no confusion with the datasource names that you use for them.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to set the datasource on the grid object using the id() method on the FormDataSource object, not just the full object.

Change from:

```
formBuildGridControl.dataSource(formBuildDatasource);
```

to:

```
formBuildGridControl.dataSource(formBuildDatasource.id());
```